# Redirecionar usuários não indetificados Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Eu tenho uma pagina Asp.net MVC, utilizando entityframework, e tenho um sistema de login :

```
  public ActionResult Index(LoginModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.Email, model.Senha))
                {
                    Pessoa pessoa = this.PessoaServico.GetMany(p => p.Email == model.Email).First();

                    if (pessoa is Lojista)
                        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboard", new { area = "Lojista" });
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                ModelState.AddModelError("erro", "Ocorreu um erro inesperado");
            }

        }

        ModelState.AddModelError("erro", "Usuário e/ou Senha Inválidos.");

        return View(model);
    }
```

Eu somente autorizo quem esta logado com a seguinde descrição `[Authorize(Roles = "Lojista")]`  a parte do login do sistema não foi eu quem fez, então estou com um pouco de dificuldades de intender o funcionamento, e quando procuro algo sobre não consigo intender muito bem.

Vi que alguns setam algumas coisas no web.config, mas não consegui entender. Caso precise de mais alguma informação e so dizer.

Comment: qual o seu sistema? MVC ou webforms? ado.net ou entityframework? fez utilizando o identity, membership ou na raça o sistema de login?

Comment: Vou melhorar a pergunta...

Comment: Minha falta de noção atrapalha na elaboração da pergunta, espero que de para intender, mas como não foi eu quem fez o login não sei o funcionamento dele, porque me disseram que o redirecionamento era feito no web.config quando não indetificassem o usuario, mas não achei nada la que relacionasse a isso.

Comment: agora ficou bem mais claro, vou responder a pergunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para fazer o redirecionamento das páginas que terão autenticação utilizando o atributo `[Authorize]` basta configurar o seu `web.config` para isso.

**Web.Config**

```
<system.web>
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Login/Index" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>

</system.web>
```

**OAuth**
Observe que sistema como Identity, configuram a url padrão de login através de um arquivo chamado `Starup.Auth.cs` dentro da pasta `App_start`
Algo como:

```
LoginPath = new PathString("/MeuUsuario/Login")
```

Comment: Cara, exatamente o que eu precisava, simples e direto, fiquei bastante tempo procurando e simplesmente não achava, muito obrigado pela paciência e pela boa vontade me ajudou muito.